# Image replacement using PDFBox does not change size of pdf according to image

Tags: pdfbox

I am using PDFBox 2.0.8 to replace image in my application. I am able to extract the image and replace the same with another image of same dimension. However, there  is no decrease in the size of PDF if there is decrease in the size of image. For example refer the documents/images in the below links. Original size of PDF is 93 KB. Extracted image is 91 KB. Replaced image is 54 KB. PDF size after image replacement is still 92 KB....

1. Original Document = http://35.200.192.44/download?fileName=/outbox/pdf/10_cert.pdf
2. Extracted Image = http://35.200.192.44/download?fileName=/outbox/pdf/image0.jpg
3. Replacement image = http://35.200.192.44/download?fileName=/outbox/pdf/image1.jpg
4. PDF after replacement = http://35.200.192.44/download?fileName=/outbox/pdf/10_cert1.pdf.

The change in size of PDF after replacement is not in the same proportion... Code snippet used for image replacement is

```java
BufferedImage buffered_replacement_image_file = ImageIO.read(new File(replacement_image_file));
PDImageXObject replacement_img = JPEGFactory.createFromImage(doc, buffered_replacement_image_file);
resources.put(xObjectName, replacement_img);
```

Comment: Since you decompress the jpg to a `BufferedImage` and then re-compress it using `JPEGFactory`, the original size has little influence. Try calling [`JPEGFactory#createFromImage`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.8/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/image/JPEGFactory.html#createFromImage(org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument,%20java.awt.image.BufferedImage,%20float)) with lower quality (0.7-0.9 is a pretty good range for acceptable quality).  I don't think there is a way to directly insert a jpg using PDFBox, but I am not sure about that.

Comment: Your files are not present anymore.

Comment: @Itai *"I don't think there is a way to directly insert a jpg using PDFBox, but I am not sure about that."* - You can do that using the `JPEGFactory` methods `createFromByteArray` or `createFromStream`.

Comment: Links should be accessible now. I want to use an in house software for image processing. Does the code snippet resources.put(xObjectName, replacement_img); does not overwrite existing image. Replacement_img is a jpg file on file system

Comment: @mkl - Good to know! For some reason I assumed all `JPEGFactory` methods expect a bitmap (essentially), even though now I look at the documentation it is clear the byte array ones take straight JPEG.

Comment: @ShailenderJain Please use 2.0.11, not 2.0.8. We continually improve the code and the documentation.

Comment: Result is the same with 2.0.11 also. Here are the results (1.1) Original PDF Size = 93 KB (1.2) Original Image Inside PDF = 92 KB  (2.1) Replaced Image size in PDF = 73 KB  (2.2) Replace Size of PDF = 154 KB..... It looks like the replacement method resources.put(xObjectName, replacement_img) does not seem to work appropriately

Answer (score 0):

The images in your two example PDFs are identical. This most likely is due to the way you load the image data, first creating a `BufferedImage` from the file and then creating a `PDImageXObject` from that `BufferedImage`. This causes the input image data to be expanded to a plain bitmap and then re-compressed to JPEG identically by `JPEGFactory.createFromImage`.

To use the JPEG data as they initially are, try this approach instead:

```java
PDImageXObject replacement_img = JPEGFactory.createFromStream(doc, new FileInputStream(replacement_image_file));
resources.put(xObjectName, replacement_img);
```

or, if the `replacement_image_file` is not necessarily a JPEG file, like this

```java
PDImageXObject replacement_img = PDImageXObject.createFromFileByExtension(new File(replacement_image_file), doc);
resources.put(xObjectName, replacement_img);
```

If this doesn't help, you most likely have other issues in your code, too, and need to show more of it.

Comment: Refer link:  http://35.200.192.44/download?fileName=/outbox/pdf/Code_Snippet.txt.... I have changed the code to JPEGFactory.createFromStream(doc, new FileInputStream(replacement_image_file));. This has created PDF with the right size. However, this has produced a PDF with garbled images. PDF looks ok when i view in Google Chrome. However, it is not ok when i view in my adobe reader. Refer link http://35.200.192.44/download?fileName=/outbox/pdf/10_cert1.pdf &  http://35.200.192.44/download?fileName=/outbox/pdf/PDF_Garbled_Image.jpg

Comment: Which Adobe Reader version are you testing that with? I tried both the current Adobe Reader DC and Adobe Acrobat 9.5, neither of those showed anything like your screen shot.

Comment: I am using version 11.0.0 on Windows 10

Comment: That is weird. As mentioned above I couldn't reproduce the problem with the current and with older adobe software.

Comment: Does this means this issue is limited to my machine? Which OS you are using?

Comment: I'm working on Windows 10 here.But are you sure it's the identical file? Please try and retrieve the file from the link you shared and open it on your machine. I cannot see anything abnormal in it.

Comment: Yes... It is the same file. It works properly on Chrome, IE, PDF Box Debugger. The only issue is with the Adobe reader

Comment: I did some more testing and it seems everything looks ok on machine if the code is run on Linux server. It could be related to JVM version. I will continue to do some more testing

Comment: Another query: Is there any similar class like JPEGFactory for PNG images

Comment: Ignore my last remark...I could see the details in previous remarks .. thanks